# Foundation - support for x(x)large?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have starting to play with Foundation and I realised there was a possibility to support larger screens but I don't know how to enable.

What I basically would like to do is being able to address larger screens (up to 1920px) and use those additional breakpoints in various ways like for example the ability to specify how many elements of a block grid have to be displayed on xxlarge, xlarge, large,...

I have checked the settings file and there are a couple of things there that seem to indicate it's possible.

I have first uncommented:

```
//$row-width: rem-calc(1000);
```

and set it to:

```
$row-width: rem-calc(1920);
```

With this I see that my addressable screen is bigger but breakpoints are still the same.

I also have uncommented this:

```
$large-breakpoint:  em-calc(1440);
$xlarge-breakpoint: em-calc(1920);
```

...etc..
(and almost everything in the d.Media query ranges section)

```
$include-xl-html-grid-classes: true;
$include-xl-html-block-grid-classes: true;
```

But even with all this enabled, breakpoints still doesn't work with a simple thing like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="xlarge-12 columns">content</div>
</div>
```

This displays a div of exactly the same size as for large-12

Any idea?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row-width` refers to the *maximum* width of content. The foundation grid is 12 columns, so any div with `{size}-12` will be 100% wide. This is why large-12 and xlarge-12 divs will be the same width.

To make the content smaller on large screens and larger on xlarge screens, try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-10 xlarge-12 columns">content</div>
</div>
```